# E22021: Character not in repertoire

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-insert, prisma

I want to add an entry with the **WebUI Prisma Studio** to the database until i have set up a form to do so. The database is postgresql hosted at **vercel** and in **version 15.**
The table i want to insert to is Todo with the following model:

```
model Todo {
  id              String   @id @default(cuid())
  title           String
  content         String?
  publicationDate DateTime @default(now())
  dueDate         String?
  finished        Boolean  @default(false)
  author          User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId        String?
}
```

However, there is a byte sequence which seems to be not valid: "**0x00**"

I want to enter the following data:

- 1
- Test
- Test sth
- 2023-10-09T22:00:00.000Z
- 10.10.23
- false
- marian-l
- cljop1hlc0000y8twqe4ee4ao

I can confirm that User and its related fields are not problematic because there are already entries of these in my db. so whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) says:

> Regardless of the specific character set, the character with code zero (sometimes called NUL) cannot be stored.

Zero bytes can be stored as binary data with data type `bytea`, but they don't make a lot of sense in strings.

Comment: i seems that i needed to add @db.Timestamp() to my publicationDate because postgres would not like the DateTime Format otherwise.